# Firebase messaging error: using service worker before get token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use FCM with angularjs, so after initializing firebase I wrote the following code:

```
messaging = firebase.messaging();
$window.navigator.serviceWorker.register($rootScope.app.base_url + '/app/lib/firebaseCustomWorker.js')
.then(function(registration) {
    messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function(){  
    messaging.getToken()
    .then(function(currentToken) {
        console.log(currentToken);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    });
}).catch(function(err){console.log(err)});
```

the problem is that the last line sometimes catches an error which appears in console with code `"messaging/use-sw-before-get-token"` and message that says:

> FirebaseError: Messaging: You must call useServiceWorker() before calling getToken() to ensure your service worker is used. (messaging/use-sw-before-get-token).

And as you can see in the code above, I only call `getToken()` after calling `useServiceWorker()` and after `requestPermission()`

I dug into the original `firebase-messaging.js` file in line 35 but unfortunately didn't get any clue of why this is happening

Answer (score 2):

I know this is probably crazy and will backfire but it works.

```
 .
 .
 .
 if('undefined' !== typeof messaging.b )
      delete(messaging.b);
 messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
 .
 .
 .
```

inspired by reading firebase-messaging.js

Comment: heh, yeah that's scary. but good job finding a workaround. Please see my answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar crazy idea to your answer:

```
if (!firebase.apps[0]) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

I found that it's better to use `firebase.initializeApp(config)` than `navigator.serviceWorker.register`. It can be called multiple times without having to worry about whether there is a service worker loaded. Just put this on every page in your app:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to user new version firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#gettoken

```
 messaging.getToken({
                        serviceWorkerRegistration: registration,
                        vapidKey: keyPair
                    }).then((currentToken) => {
                        if (currentToken) {
                            console.log(currentToken)
                        } else {
                            // Show permission request UI
                            console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                        }
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                    });
```